# Is there a PropertyGrid attribute that can raise an event?

Tags: c#, events, propertygrid

In C#, when using a class for a PropertyGrid, am I correct in saying that there is an attribute that can be used to raise an event when a property is changed?

I cannot seem to find this. Can someone please help me out?

**EDIT**

I am looking for the attribute, similar to the Browsable attribute, where I can add an event name, and this event is raised when the property is changed. This is for collections mainly, but also for all other properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [PropertyGrid.PropertyValueChanged-Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertyvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)? Or are you looking for something different?